# Why are some websites in Safari not going through iCloud Private Relay?

Tags: icloud, network, safari, icloud-plus

Ever since upgrading to iOS 17 I have gotten this warning on certain websites:

> **This Connection Is Not Private**
>
> iCloud Private Relay is unable to hide your IP address from this site.
> By continuing to "[SITE NAME]" your IP address will be revealed.
>
> Show IP Address / Close Page

When I go to the same site(s) on a Mac running Ventura, the site loads without any warning, and the option to "Reload and Show IP Address" in the View tab of Safari does not appear for those websites. In addition, one of those sites shows the IP Address I am using, and it's my "original" IP address - not an iCloud Private Relay one.

Why do certain sites not load through iCloud Private Relay?

Update: I found sites will load outside Private Relay without warning. Some sites will make the initial connection via Private Relay, but randomly go "outside" the service mid-browsing and lose the Private Relay privacy protections without warning.

My concern is that sites can exploit this vulnerability by embedding a "non-Private-Relay" domain or site in their existing site, giving the site access to a user's IP address without warning.

Comment: It would help if you listed a few sites which give you this problem. Otherwise answers can only be guesses.

Comment: Private relay has to make use of a proxy server. Some sites block access from proxy servers, because they need to get the real IP to determine its geographic location.

Comment: Here is an example website, which i just encountered- https://www.reecesupply.com/

Comment: Another site I encountered the issue on is [mybell.bell.ca](https://mybell.bell.ca)

Comment: @Barmar If that was the case, it would only be blocked on the website's servers, the website can't dictate that the device bypass Private Relay. If there is a way for websites to do that, especially without notifying users, that's a massive failure of Apple

Comment: Apple may have compiled a list of these sites so it can provide this convenience feature.

Comment: I noticed that this issue differs based on the Egress Relay used. When Private Relay uses Cloudflare as an Egress relay, this issue occurs. When using Fastly as an Egress Relay, it doesn't (or at least hasn't yet).

Comment: @Barmar Just saw your new comment as I was writing the other one. Maybe the Egress Relay (or Apple) has a "list" of sites that aren't routed through Private Relay. If that's the case, that's a major privacy failure to not release that list or notify customers that sites are not being routed through Private Relay, especially when Apple markets Private Relay as "ensuring that when you browse the web in Safari, no single party — not even Apple — can see both who you are and what sites you're visiting."

Comment: What do you mean they're not notifying customers? The message you quoted is the notification.

Comment: @Barmar This message was only introduced in iOS 17 and MacOS Sonoma. Private Relay has been available since iOS 15 and macOS Monterey, and this issue has been occurring since. I'm sure a lot of customers - including myself - have used Private Relay over the last two years believing that their web traffic was being routed through Private Relay, when in fact it wasn't. Apple has never said that certain sites were excluded.

Comment: I was just trying to explain this message, not what was happening before the message was added.

Comment: @Barmar Right. I'm focused on the Private Relay leak.

Comment: I don't know what's going on in the versions that don't display the message.