# How does iCloud Private Relay handle HTTP requests outside of Safari?

Tags: icloud, privacy

How does iCloud Private Relay handle connections that are HTTP in other browsers like Brave or Chrome?

I know that it only masks your IP address completely when you're using Safari - but - it also seems like (If I am understanding correctly) if a connection in an app is running without SSL it'll automatically "upgrade" the connection by routing it through Private Relay.

So, I guess, my question is if I am using Private Relay on my Mac or my iPhone and I'm browsing with Brave will it route me through private relay if I visit a HTTP only site?

I'm not aware of any sites that tell you your IP that don't run over SSL, so I have not been able to test it myself.

I'm coming up on the end of my renewal for my VPN and curious if iCloud Private Relay will be enough. I only use it to protect myself on public WiFi and don't really care about anonymity outside of the local network nor location masking.

Comment: Totally depends on the device.  Answer is completely different on Mac vs iPhone.  Suggest you edit the question to ask about one or the other.  And/or look at existing answers.

Comment: I'd like to know how it works on both, though! :) -- I didn't see a great answer for that when I searched for "iCloud Private Relay".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an HTTP ["Show my IP"](http://en.dnstools.ch/show-my-ip.html) site.

I tested this on both my Mac and iPhone using (different ones on both) 3rd party browsers. Both showed an iCloud Private Relay Address, not my "actual" IP Address. On the same Apps/Browsers, an IP Address site that loads through TLS shows my ISP's IP. FWIW, I tested this a few years back when iCloud Private Relay was first released, and I got the same result (a Private Relay IP address). I imagine you'd get the same result.

> my question is if I am using Private Relay on my Mac or my iPhone and I'm browsing with Brave will it route me through private relay if I visit a HTTP only site?

iCloud Private Relay has a leak (amongst many) where some sites, even in Safari, aren't routed through the service (for some unknown reason), and in many cases without warning. The way it's supposed to work, it will only route the insecure connections via Private Relay. Any secure connections will continue to be routed outside Private Relay. That means secure links, images, etc, even on a "Not Secure" site, will go through the network provider's connection.

> I'm coming up on the end of my renewal for my VPN and curious if iCloud Private Relay will be enough. I only use it to protect myself on public WiFi and don't really care about anonymity outside of the local network nor location masking.

It depends what you mean by "enough" and "protect". What would you like to achieve with these services? If you simply want to have some degree of preventing insecure web traffic floating around public Wi-Fi, iCloud Private Relay is better than nothing, but it has far too many failures - against Apple's claims - that it can be trusted to be reliable.

Sharing what specific goals you have would help in finding the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the share, I tested that on iOS using Brave and can confirm that it shows a iCloud Private Relay IP address - but - on macOS using Brave it shows my ISPs IP address. Honestly, that's fine - I'm mostly concerned about iOS. As far as what I care about it's as noted above. I only care about MITM type attacks on the local public WiFi (conventions, coffee shops, etc). I don't care about geoshifting or hiding my IP address. VPN works great on macOS but it has always been a pain for me on iOS, so I guess my biggest goal is staying secure from MITM on Public WiFi without a VPN.

Comment: Odd. Are you still having that issue on Brave for Mac? If so, does your actual IP address appear on another 3rd party browser with the same site? I'm curious to know if it's a Brave thing or Private Relay thing. When I used this site on Brave for Mac, I saw an iCloud Private Relay Address.

Comment: Yeah, it shows my true IP in Firefox & Brave -- just confirmed.

Comment: If you go to the same site (not HTTP-IP) in Safari, do you get the same result?

Comment: Also, just for my understanding; by MITM, what is your primary concern? Are you concerned about an attacker stealing sensitive information (like credit card numbers?), or are you concerned with someone on the network being able to see your browsing patterns/sites visited?

Comment: It does my IP in Safari too - yes - but while I do have Private Relay enabled I don't have it enabled in Safari. Yes that is my concern and my only one. I often don't get service in bigger buildings (IE: Home Depo) so I hop on the WiFi and would like to be protected from a bad actor reading my traffic/dns/etc. I use a VPN for it now but VPN on iOS is awful to say the least.

Comment: In that case, it might be something to do with how your device is configured rather than a Private Relay bug.

Comment: With that being said, Private Relay does have leaks, including DNS leaks, so if you need a complete solution, you’re going to need to stick to a reliable VPN. I get that iOS doesn’t play work well with VPNs, but Private Relay just hides the bugs better. It’s also limited, only applying Safari and insecure traffic (if/when it works). Given almost all web traffic is encrypted nowadays, it may be worth asking how much value an attacker can get when not using either.

Comment: On today’s web, the “big bad” are data brokers, not “eavesdrop on your connection and steal your bank login” hackers as much anymore. Things like DNS queries and SNI provide a lot of value for selling web traffic, but not very much for hackers. Going to “https://www.BankOfMoney.com” more likely results in you getting ads for “BankComparison.com” than someone intercepting your bank logins. Web security and/or privacy is extremely complex with many considerations and there’s no simple solution. But if this is a concern for you, then a reliable VPN would be an additional layer, not a total fix.

Comment: (But you have to get a VPN that has proven, usually through audits, to be trustworthy. Otherwise you’re just kicking the can down the road, and the data becomes the marketable property of the VPN)

Comment: Do you by chance have a resource for the leaks found in private relay? I've done some searching and I see DNS leaks commonly cited, but it sounds like there are others based on your comment? Truth be told I don't mind much about DNS leaks, so that'd be fine with me. I just want to make sure everything is running over SSL.

Comment: Other than yours, I have not heard of a case where a Private Relay user found unencrypted traffic leaving their device. But I also don't think many have tested it. Most people don't do constant traffic analysis and I can't say I have looked into this either. I just don’t trust it. All of Apple’s core claims about the service have been provably false. Encrypted DNS Records? It leaks to the network DNS. All Safari web traffic? Some sites randomly leave private relay without warning. No single party? The same corporation runs both servers. iCloud Private Relay is an illusion of privacy

Comment: Take a look at my question here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/464644/506202 . I’m looking into why this occurs. So far I suspect it has something to do with certain sites blocking name resolution from certain resolvers or IP addresses, but I haven’t determined that conclusively. If you want ‘everything” running over SSL (on macOS/iOS, it will never truly be “everything”), then what’s to say this issue doesn’t occur when trying to communicate with the server where the unencrypted data is going? In that case, it wouldn’t be “everything”. But who says iOS doesn't do the same to VPNs?

Comment: If any unencrypted data is a major issue to you, a VPN will get you as close as possible to moving that number to zero. If it's not that important, and you just want to "feel" protected, and albeit, still get closer to zero, then iCloud Private Relay is enough. But you'd be paying for comfort. The vast majority of unencrypted data on today's web is worthless to hackers. But given this is a concern to you, it suggests even a small bit of unencrypted data is worthy of you protecting it, and if you'd like to protect that small bit, you can't rely on a service that has proven to be unreliable.